# Save 1-band-raster to geopackage results in 4-band-raster

Tags: qgis, raster, geopackage

I have a 1-band-raster (geotiff) and want to export it to a geopackage in QGIS 3.14. When I do that (right-click --> export --> save as), it results in a 4-band-raster. How can I prevent that?

Comment: It would help if you edited your question and provided some details about your geotiff, either the output of  `gdalinfo yourgeotiff.tif` or copy the contents of layer properties - information tab in QGIS and paste as text (formatted as code) into your question.

Comment: GDAL seems to assume 4 bands when converting to GeoPackage for Int type data, and 1 band for Float type data. So if your GeoTIFF is in Int format, try converting from Type=Byte/Int16 etc to a Float type (Float32/Float64) when you save to GeoPackage, assuming the Type is not critical.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the tiles are stored with 1 band but GDAL just reports that there are 4 bands. That is documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html

> Opening options
>
> By default, the driver will expose a GeoPackage
> dataset as a four band (Red,Green, Blue,Alpha) dataset, which gives
> the maximum compatibility with the various encodings of tiles that can
> be stored. It is possible to specify an explicit number of bands with
> the BAND_COUNT opening option.

I had a test by converting 1-band GeoTIFF into GeoPackage and gdalinfo indeed behaves as documented.

```
gdalinfo 1_band_gdal.gpkg
...
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha

gdalinfo 1_band_gdal.gpkg -oo band_count=1
…
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```